# Получить/изменить данные в БД mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Записал данные в БД таким образом:

```
<?php
// мой массив

$data = [
    "id" => $_POST['id'],
    "name" => $_POST['name'],
    "phone" => $_POST['phone'],
    "address" => $_POST['address'],
    "city" => $_POST['city'],
    "email" => $_POST['email'],
    "auto" => $_POST['auto']
];

// подключаюсь

$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ex01', 'root', '');

$sql = 'INSERT INTO `conts` (`id`, `name`, `phone`, `address`, `city`, `email`, `auto`) VALUES (:id, :name, :phone, :address, :city, :email, :auto)';
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$result = $statement->execute($data);

var_dump($result);

?>

// Аналогичным ajax-ом записываю в БД

// этой кнопкой запрашиваю получить данные из БД
$('button.open_conts').on('click', function(){

                $.ajax({
                    url:"test.php",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(responce){
                    // в этот див хочу получить данные 
                        $('#all_conts').html(responce); 
                    }
                })
            });
```

Этот код записывает в мою заготовленную таблицу данные. А как получить/отредактировать эти записанные данные из БД? Никак не получается, помогите реализовать, понимаю что нужно сделать запрос типа

```
SELECT * FROM `conts` WHERE 1
```

но как это описать в коде не понимаю.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM conts WHERE id=:id`

Comment: А как это описать, можно немного подробнее?

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/select#prepare

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/137664/ https://prowebmastering.ru/php-pdo-start.html https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php